# Problema con Visual Studio 2019 al abrir WinForms Designer con .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, .net, .net-core

He intentado crear un proyecto de Windows Forms con .NET Core, estoy utilizando la version preview 4.0 de Visual Studio 2019, 16.5.0, el proyecto compila, se ejecuta correctamente, no hay ningun error mas que el diseñador, he probado las soluciones que publica microsoft, de utilizar como dependencia el diseñador de Windows Forms del .NET Framework pero nada, he probado ejecutando como usuario y como administrador y no hay cambios, adjunto imagenes.

[image: Codigo de error de Visual Studio 2019]

[image: Version de Visual Studio 2019]

Comment: Amigo, desgraciadamente ese error es casi generico a vista de nosotros. Podrías ocupar lo [siguiente](http://ig2600.blogspot.com/2009/07/finding-clr-exceptions-with-visual.html) como guía y encontrarás el error mas facilmente. Publica tus resultados

Comment: Puedes leer esta pregunta de [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244939/how-do-i-fix-a-net-windows-application-crashing-at-startup-with-exception-code) y seguir los pasos. En resumen es que vayas debugando tu aplicacion paso a paso y fijarte cuando lanza el error